# How kill or destroy the either root window or child window

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import xlrd as rd

class Example():
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.frameExample =tk.Frame(master,width =600,height = 200)
        self.frameExample.pack()

        self.loadButton = tk.Button(self.frameExample,text = "Load",command =self.loadFile)
        self.loadButton.pack()


    def loadFile(self):
        sheetWindow = tk.Toplevel()
        sheetFrame = tk.Frame(sheetWindow, width = 600,height = 400,bg = "alice blue")        
        sheetFrame.pack()

        try:
            print("entered")
            self.workbook = rd.open_workbook("tiger.jpg")

        except:
            print("entered 1")
            messagebox.showinfo(title = "Load error",message = "Error")
            self.master.destroy()


root = tk.Tk()
Example(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I have tried `self.masterdestroy()`, not sure how to kill main window

Comment: There are several questions and answers about destroying windows in tkinter, and the method to do so is well documented. Please explain what you've done to debug this, and what research you've done. It's unclear why you need help, since information to solve your problem is readily available.

Comment: I am able to destroy the frame or even the 2nd window, self.frameExample .destroy() or  self.sheetWindow .destroy() , but not able to find a place which kills the root window from the above code...moreover i was not able to find any examples for above scenario..If any url  or stackoverflow discussion is there please share me the same - Tried self.master.destroy(), not working...

Comment: To be more clear i am able to destroy it without having class,

Comment: import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import xlrd as rd
root = tk.Tk()
def loadFile():
sheetWindow = tk.Toplevel()
sheetFrame = tk.Frame(sheetWindow)        
sheetFrame.pack()        
try:
print("entered")
self.workbook = rd.open_workbook("tiger.jpg")
except:
print("entered 1")
messagebox.showinfo(title = "Load error",message = "Error")
sheetWindow.destroy()
root.destroy()
frameExample =tk.Frame(root,width =600,height = 200)
frameExample.pack()
loadButton = tk.Button(frameExample,text = "Load",command =loadFile)
loadButton.pack()
root.mainloop()

Comment: Please don't post code in the comment section.

Comment: Sure @BryanOakley Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `self.master = master` to your `__init__` method and then your code should work.